# Overflow hidden without position relative

Tags: css, responsive-design, statistics, overflow, diagram

Overflow hidden not working for the list-element, if it not contains position relative. I do not want no static width on the div:s and prefer to solve it without any script. The code looks like this.  https://jsfiddle.net/pbahhtce/3/

```
<style>
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    li {
        height: 1.5em;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: width 1000ms linear 0s;
    }

    div {
        background: rgb(255,0,0);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,240,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,255,0,1) 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(255,240,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,255,0,1)));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,240,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,240,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,240,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,240,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,255,0,1) 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#00ff00',GradientType=1 );

        height: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<ul>
     <li style="width: 100%"><div></div></li>
     <li style="width: 75%"><div></div></li>
     <li style="width: 50%"><div></div></li>
     <li style="width: 25%"><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

This is what it should look like https://jsfiddle.net/pbahhtce/6/. But I want the div elements to be 100% to make the gradient fully responsive without using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to hide?  You have no content in the `<li>` elements.  Your gradient background is applied to your `<ul>`.  See the fiddle below - if you apply a background to the `<li>` is adheres to your width specs.

Sorry if I'm mis-understanding the question.

https://jsfiddle.net/pbahhtce/1/

EDIT:

Updated your fiddle to include `position: relative;` on the `<li>` and it works fine.  Are you looking for something else?

https://jsfiddle.net/pbahhtce/5/

Comment: You were right! Sorry. The background gradient was ment for the div:s. I have changed the code now.

Comment: I updated your updated fiddle in my response.  Adding position:relative to the <li> works...did you need something else?  You actually don't eve need overflow:hidden as the background respects the width of the <li>.

Comment: You should not see any green in the last list element.

Comment: Not sure of a way to accomplish that outside of applied separate gradients to each <li> item.  You can't hide what isn't overflowing out of a div and since the background gradient is applied to the parent div there is nothing to hide when you apply the overflow:hidden to the div since there are no contents in the div...only a background on the parent <li> element.

Answer (score -1):

not sure why position:relative is an issue for you here, but you could instead drop the position:absolute on the divs to solve the overflow issue.

see http://jsfiddle.net/pbahhtce/2/

```
div {
 /* position:absolute; */
 background:black; /* for demonstration purposes */
}
```

Comment: You can see that the list elements renders the same width right now https://jsfiddle.net/pbahhtce/3/

Comment: as mentioned in my answer, you need to remove position:absolute on the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/pbahhtce/4/ ?

Comment: I want the gradient on the div:s, and not in the background of the list. The list elements must have the same width as the list, so the smallest is only red and the longest is red to green.

Comment: hm. how about using a fixed width (e.g. 500px for both <ul> and <div> elements)? http://jsfiddle.net/pbahhtce/7/

Comment: Nothing should have a fixed width, a width in percent would make it scale better for different resolutions.

Comment: been thinking some time about the issue, but looks like i have to give up at this point. only thing i could think of is using some sort of svg masking for the gradient bars, but browser support is fishy here, see https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/